# Unable to get a vimeo video to work with fancybox-- I feel like I've tried everything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I'm quite new to both html/css and jQuery. I'm trying to get a vimeo video to open with fancybox on my page. I've read a bunch of similar questions on stackoverflow and nothing has worked. I've even put my code into JSFiddle and it WORKS. (http://jsfiddle.net/8hMLb/1/)

Heres my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <!-- Fancybox Javascript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',
          helpers : {
              media : {}
          }
      });
  });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<a class="fancybox-media" href="http://vimeo.com/70926140">Vimeo.</a>
</body>
```

I've triple triple checked that source files are correct. It works for images, just not vimeo (or youtube, or any media). It works in JSFiddle. I'm totally stumped here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: just either fancybox.js or fancybox.pack.js but not both

Comment: ah I see, thanks! this didnt solve it though

Comment: normally, the media helpers is under a helpers subdirectory, os are you sure this path `fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox-media.js` shouldn't be `fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js`? if only videos that rely on the media helpers are not working, then most likely that file is not included properly

Comment: I had moved it up a level on my own. I just tried moving it back and extending the path for the sake of trying, but to no avail. Thanks for your efforts... I cant understand why this doesn't work

Comment: if you share a link, I can tell you why

Comment: share a link to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the fact that I was working locally was the issue. When I uploaded a test version of the code to the actual site, it worked. I guess my local environment was having trouble getting to vimeo.com or something